# Looping Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is 'for(var item in list)' with arrays considered bad practice in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265167/why-is-forvar-item-in-list-with-arrays-considered-bad-practice-in-javascript)

Is it a best practice to loop through a JavaScript array using a `for..in` loop?

```
var a = [1,2,3];
for(var x in a){
//dance
}
```

Or should I be using a fully written loop?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626530/wrapping-for-in-loops-with-if-statements-in-javascript-looping-over-arrays

Comment: This has been asked many times..

Comment: The first link here is super useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `for..in`, you are looping through all of the **Array Object's properties**, including inherited ones through the prototype model.

More recent browsers have a way of making properties non-`Enumerable`, meaning they won't show up in a `for..in` loop. In these browsers, you can safely use `for..in` on an array. HOWEVER, older browsers will behave in unexpected ways. So just because you *can* use `for..in` doesn't mean you should. In fact, you shouldn't. Use `for(i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++)` for best results.

Comment: Thank you. That is preciously what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it considered best practices to loop through an array in JavaScript
>   using a for in loop?

No. For arrays, the recommended way is to use a normal loop without the `in` keyword.

```
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i <= len; i++){
  // your code here
}
```

On the other hand, `for-in` construct is useful to transverse javascript **objects**:

```
for (var i in someObj){
  if (someObj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
     // code here
  }
}
```

---

[More info on MDN docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 2):

best way (optimized) is to do

```
var len = a.length
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use anonymous function to lock array indexer inside loop.

```
(function() {
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i <= len; i++){
  // your code here
};
})();

alert(i); // undefined
```

It provides you better encapsulation and no way to use indexer variable out of loop

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [];
for(var x in a){
  b.push(x);
}
alert(b);
```

Run this code in jsfiddle.net to get answer yourself. As Kolink mentioned this gives you all properties of array not just elements.

Answer (score -2):

This is definitely better than using indexes in fors as it is much more functional-like and allows for internal optimisation of the iteration process.